# How do I implement a numerically stable weighted logaddexp?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, numerical-stability

What is the most numerically stable way of calculating:

```
log[(wx * exp(x) + wy * exp_y)/(wx + wy)]
```

where the weights `wx, wy > 0`?

Without the weights, this function is `logaddexp` and could be implemented in Python with NumPy as:

```
tmp = x - y
return np.where(tmp > 0,
                x + np.log1p(np.exp(-tmp)),
                y + np.log1p(np.exp(tmp)))
```

How should I generalize this to the weighted version?

Comment: scipy.special.logsumexp has the desired behavior, with a weights parameter b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the original `logaddexp` function for thus purpose, if you rewrite the weighted expression as,

[image: new logadd expression]

This is equivalent to,

```
logaddexp( x + log(w_x), y + log(w_y) ) - log(w_x + w_y)
```

which should be as numerically stable as the original `logaddexp` implementation.

**Note:** I'm referring to the [`numpy.logaddexp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) function that takes in `x` and `y`, not `x` and `exp_y`, as you mention in the question.

Comment: Looks like it is probably better than what I did, which I will add as an answer for comparison.

Comment: For anyone reading, I tested this using the arbitrary-precision library `mpmath` and found that it is much better than my solution.

Comment: @NeilG Yeah, I suppose no matter how you rewrite it, you are still going to loose in precision/overflow with 64 bit floats etc, when taking an exponential of large numbers and computing the log back. `mpmath` does seem to be a good choice here, although it will be slower.

Comment: I'm not using `mpmath` in my code. I just used it to measure the average error of each of our solutions so that I could know which was actually better.  `mpmath` gives an arbitrary-precision answer.  My intuition when writing my solution was to use `log1p` as much possible.  This turned out to be much worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
def weighted_logaddexp(x, wx, y, wy):
    # Returns:
    #   log[(wx * exp(x) + wy * exp_y)/(wx + wy)]
    #   = log(wx/(wx+wy)) + x + log(1 + exp(y - x + log(wy)-log(wx)))
    #   = log1p(-wy/(wx+wy)) + x + log1p((wy exp_y) / (wx exp(x)))
    if wx == 0.0:
        return y
    if wy == 0.0:
        return x
    total_w = wx + wy
    first_term = np.where(wx > wy,
                          np.log1p(-wy / total_w),
                          np.log1p(-wx / total_w))
    exp_x = np.exp(x)
    exp_y = np.exp(y)
    wx_exp_x = wx * exp_x
    wy_exp_y = wy * exp_y
    return np.where(wy_exp_y < wx_exp_x,
                    x + np.log1p(wy_exp_y / wx_exp_x),
                    y + np.log1p(wx_exp_x / wy_exp_y)) + first_term
```

---

Here's how I compared the two solutions:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp
from tools.numpy import weighted_logaddexp

def average_error(ideal_function, test_function, n_args):
    x_y = [np.linspace(0.1, 3, 20) for _ in range(n_args)]
    xs_ys = np.meshgrid(*x_y)

    def e(*args):
        return ideal_function(*args) - test_function(*args)
    e = np.frompyfunc(e, n_args, 1)
    error = e(*xs_ys) ** 2
    return np.mean(error)


def ideal_function(x, wx, y, wy):
    return mp.log((mp.exp(x) * wx + mp.exp(y) * wy) / mp.fadd(wx, wy))

def test_function(x, wx, y, wy):
    return np.logaddexp(x + math.log(wx), y + math.log(wy)) - math.log(wx + wy)

mp.prec = 100
print(average_error(ideal_function, weighted_logaddexp, 4))
print(average_error(ideal_function, test_function, 4))
```